# word spacing not working in safari

Tags: html, css, browser, xhtml, safari

Hi I was hoping if someone can help me with an issue I am having in Safari. Basically I have created a [website](http://www.islandtoislandshipping.com)

If you look on the top menu at the navigation bar, there is word and letter spacing in Google Chrome, IE, Firefox and Opera. However, when opening this website in Safari, there is no word spacing.

Here is the code copy and pasted on the bottom:

```
    <nav id="top_menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="destination.html">Destinations</a></li>
            <li><a href="products.html">Products</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
       </ul>
    </nav>
```

And here is the CSS for this code:

```
#top_menu {
        margin-left:170px;
        letter-spacing:1px;
        word-spacing:50px;
}

#top_menu li {
    display:inline-block;
    list-style:none;
    padding:5px;
    font:bold 14px Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    position:relative;
    bottom:40px;
}

#top_menu li a { 
    border-bottom: none; 
}

#top_menu a {
    color:#FFF;
    text-decoration: none; 
    border-bottom: 1px solid #7ac000; 
    padding-bottom: 2px; 
}

#top_menu a:hover { 
    color: #ff5400; 
    text-decoration: none; 
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ff5400; 
    padding-bottom: 2px; 
}

#top_menu a:active { 
    color: #ff5400; 
    text-decoration: none; 
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ff5400; 
    padding-bottom: 2px; 
    position: relative; top: 1px; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

hi if you don't mind what is the purpose of using `word-spacing:50px;` if the idea is to have space between two `<a>` use `padding` to your `li` and eliminate `word-spacing` in `#top_menu`

```
#top_menu {
        margin-left:170px;
        letter-spacing:1px;
}

#top_menu li {
    display:inline-block;
    list-style:none;
    padding:5px 15px 5px 0;
    font:bold 14px Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    position:relative;
    bottom:40px;
}
```

I know this is not the perfect answer, but hopefully this can help you....

Comment: Hi people, thank you for your answers, I decided to ditch the previous navigation bar and designed one in Photoshop and imported into Dreamweaver. Thanks Jhunlio however, at least next time I know to work through the padding instead of using word-spacing.

Comment: Here is an example when you need word-spacing: we use inline-blocks and text-align: justify. Still we do not want to merge list items, we want at least 50px spacing. Adding padding would break justify. Even oldest IE and Firefox will support word-spacing, but not Chrome and Safari in this case.

Answer (score -1):

Just Add Like This :

```css
#top_menu {
     margin-left:170px;
     letter-spacing:1px;
     word-spacing:50px;
    -webkit-word-spacing:50px;
    -moz-letter-spacing:1
    -moz-word-spacing:50px;
    -webkit-letter-spacing:1
#top_menu li {
     display:inline-block;
     list-style:none;
     padding:5px;
     font:bold 14px Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
     position:relative;
     bottom:40px;
 }

  #top_menu li a { 
     border-bottom: none; 
  }

  #top_menu a {
      color:#FFF;
      text-decoration: none; 
      border-bottom: 1px solid #7ac000; 
      padding-bottom: 2px; 
  }

  #top_menu a:hover { 
      color: #ff5400; 
      text-decoration: none; 
      border-bottom: 1px solid #ff5400; 
      padding-bottom: 2px; 
  }

  #top_menu a:active { 
      color: #ff5400; 
      text-decoration: none; 
      border-bottom: 1px solid #ff5400; 
      padding-bottom: 2px; 
      position: relative; top: 1px; 
  }
```

```html
    <nav id="top_menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="destination.html">Destinations</a></li>
            <li><a href="products.html">Products</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
       </ul>
    </nav>
```